# How to extract characters left of a number in a string?

Tags: stata

I have a set of medication descriptors in Stata that I want to standardize. I want to extract the name of the drug that is found in the first word or two of the string. The name is followed by either a whole number, a percentage, or a range. There is a possibility that a number might be included in the name, as seen in the entry below for "SM SINUS 12HR". Is there a way to extract the string section that comes before a number in the string? What I want to accomplish is shown below:

| drug_name | new_name |
| --- | --- |
| SM MICONAZOLE 3 COMBO PACK | SM MICONAZOLE |
| SM SALINE 0.65% NASAL SPRAY | SM SALINE |
| SM SINUS 12HR 120 MG CAPLET | SM SINUS 12HR |
| SM MOTION SICKNESS 25 MG TAB | SM MOTION SICKNESS |
| ATENOLOL-CHLORTHAL 50-25 TB | ATENOLOL-CHLORTHAL |
| OXYMORPHONE HCL 10 MG TABLET | OXYMORPHONE HCL |
| D-AMPHETAMINE ER 10 MG CAPSULE | D-AMPHETAMINE ER |
| LISINOPRIL-HYDROCHLOROTHIAZIDE 20-25 MG TAB | LISINOPRIL-HYDROCHLOROTHIAZIDE |
| SOD SULFACE-SULF 9.8-4.8% CLSR | SOD SULFACE-SULF |

Alternatively, is there a way to extract the desired name if we ignore numeric values in the name of the drugs? Imitating the table above with the difference being the "12HR" observation:

| drug_name | new_name |
| --- | --- |
| SM SINUS 12HR 120 MG CAPLET | SM SINUS |

Comment: It can be done with a language / tool that supports regular expressions. "From the beginning until the first digit" is easy to implement.

Comment: Your inclusion of "12 HR" in one name seems to contradict your stated rules, or imply that they are more complicated than you say.

Comment: @NickCox You are right. I tried to specify this by saying "The name is followed by a number, either a whole number, a percentage, or a range." What would be the solution if I were to edit my table to not include the "12HR" in the new name? Could I edit my current question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `regexs` and `regexm`. (Two guides I find useful: [Stata](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/regular-expressions/) and [UCLA](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-can-i-extract-a-portion-of-a-string-variable-using-regular-expressions/).)

The `gen new_name` line grabs the first string of letters, spaces, and dashes `([ a-zA-Z-]*)` before encountering a space followed by a number `([ ][0-9]*)`. I also put a line to extract the number of hours if you wanted that too.

First we input the data:

```
clear 
input str100 drug_name
"SM MICONAZOLE 3 COMBO PACK"
"SM SALINE 0.65% NASAL SPRAY"
"SM SINUS 12HR 120 MG CAPLET"
"SM MOTION SICKNESS 25 MG TAB"
"ATENOLOL-CHLORTHAL 50-25 TB"
"OXYMORPHONE HCL 10 MG TABLET"
"D-AMPHETAMINE ER 10 MG CAPSULE"
"D-AMPHETAMINE ER 10 MG CAPSULE 8HR" // added for additional testing
end
```

Next here are the `regexs`/`regexm` lines to extract drug name and hour:

```
gen new_name = regexs(1) if regexm(drug_name, "([ a-zA-Z-]*)([ ][0-9]*)")
gen hours    = regexs(1) if regexm(drug_name, "([0-9]*HR)")
```

This line concatenates name and hour:

```
gen new_name_and_hours = trim(new_name + " " + hours)
```

And here's the result:

```
. list drug_name new_name new_name_and_hours

     +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |                          drug_name             new_name     new_name_and_hours |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |         SM MICONAZOLE 3 COMBO PACK        SM MICONAZOLE          SM MICONAZOLE |
  2. |        SM SALINE 0.65% NASAL SPRAY            SM SALINE              SM SALINE |
  3. |        SM SINUS 12HR 120 MG CAPLET             SM SINUS          SM SINUS 12HR |
  4. |       SM MOTION SICKNESS 25 MG TAB   SM MOTION SICKNESS     SM MOTION SICKNESS |
  5. |        ATENOLOL-CHLORTHAL 50-25 TB   ATENOLOL-CHLORTHAL     ATENOLOL-CHLORTHAL |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |       OXYMORPHONE HCL 10 MG TABLET      OXYMORPHONE HCL        OXYMORPHONE HCL |
  7. |     D-AMPHETAMINE ER 10 MG CAPSULE     D-AMPHETAMINE ER       D-AMPHETAMINE ER |
  8. | D-AMPHETAMINE ER 10 MG CAPSULE 8HR     D-AMPHETAMINE ER   D-AMPHETAMINE ER 8HR |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I added a line at the end of your data to show that the hours extraction works when it's at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

A very nice solution to your problem would be regular expressions.

A brief introduction to regular expressions: https://www.sitepoint.com/learn-regex/

You can read how to use them inside stata here: https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/regular-expressions/

The regular expression you are looking for would be `"(.+) [\d\W]+ "`, and take the text out of the first capture group.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Are you able to provide an example? Unfortunately I am not getting the desired results in my implementation.